# Android Intent-filter for GEO-URI

Tags: android, intentfilter

I try to write an Activity as an alternative to google maps.
It works perfect when calling it by an google-maps url:

```
<activity android:name="DataActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maps.google.com" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But for some reason it does not shown up when starting an Intent with a "geo"-URI.

My Activity:

```
<activity android:name="DataActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" android:host="*" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The Caller (This starts Google Maps without the option to start my App):

```
final String uri = "geo:" + lat + "," + lng;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Comment: how do you resolve the geo uri in your app to get the location data ?

Answer (score 13):

try with

```
<intent-filter android:priority="0">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="geo"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: priority is obsolete

Answer (score 8):

Correct way to add multiple schemes :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="geo"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="google.navigation"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="maps.google.com"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="maps.google.com"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: "maps.google.com" on http and https not working for me, any problems known, have an s7 with 6.0.1 latest android … just my app ist triggered at all…

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   <data android:scheme="geo"/>
   <data android:scheme="google.navigation"/>
</intent-filter>
```

It's worked for me.