# How to add own application to the list of Maps Applications?

Tags: android, android-intent

If some other application wants to show something on the map (uses link *geo:lat,lng*), then before showing the map, it shows 'Maps Applications' list. So, I could choose which map application should be started.

How can I add my own application to this list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) shows the various URL formats used to launch Google apps (including maps). To launch maps you would use:

```
try {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,       
        Uri.parse("geo:0.00,0.00"));
    startActivity(myIntent);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) { }
```

If you want the user to be presented with the option to open your app instead of Google Maps, then you have to register to handle the same Intent in your manifest, maybe something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369012/android-intent-filter-for-geo-uri).

Comment: my question is related to the second part of your answer. So, I need to add `<data android:scheme="geo"/>` to add my application to Maps list, right?

Comment: Check out the second link (on the final word of my response). That provides an example of what you need to do.

Comment: How to parse geo data inside the App? From which variables or how?