# How to register my navigation app for implicit navigation intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, implicit

I want my navigation-app to be called via implicit intents from other apps. So I guess I need to "register" my app for such navigation-intents in its Manifest. But how exactly can I "register" as a navigation app? I guess the intent tags must follow a specific rule otherwise it will not work.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369012/android-intent-filter-for-geo-uri

Answer (score 0):

It should be this one :
http://www.openintents.org/en/node/820

I think that you'll have to register it in your manifest.xml with something like :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <data android:scheme="google.navigation"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: i guess i should catch intents like that: `String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));`  but how?

Comment: You command does not "catch" intent, it "throws" one ! Anyway, the correct syntax is in the link I provided in my answer...

Comment: I see that I wrote it a bit confusing, sorry for that. I know that this command throws it. Thats why I said that I want to catch such intents. At the link you provided, i can only read how to throw it, not to catch.

Comment: Did you try the same manifest extract, with `android:scheme="geo"` ?

Comment: Yes, no breakthrough until now.

Comment: Maybe just `<data android:pathPrefix="geo:"` ?