# android, provide navigation service

Tags: android, navigation, android-service

I use some Siri-like assistant apps on my Android phone. Whenever I want the assistant to route me to somewhere, it automatically brings up the built-in Google (or Android) navigation apps. Now I created my own apps (doing slightly different things).
What service should I provide so that when the navigation command is triggered, it will pop ups and compete with the Google apps, and user can select to use it as default apps next time?

Thanks.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/4392898/802469

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated to respond to Tung Mai Le's comments.

To get your app listed to handle the google.navigation intent I created a small program to test out my previous answer.  It worked fine so I am not sure where the issue is.

Running on HTC phone with Android 4.0, I am not sure what version of Android you are using, or if your device is rooted etc.

The Complete Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.navigation.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
                <data android:scheme="google.navigation" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

The complete code (no attempts to parse)

```
package com.navigation.com;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mIntent = getIntent(); 
        if (parseNavigationIntent(mIntent)) {

        {
    }

    private Intent mIntent = null; 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);


        return true;
    }
}



private boolean parseNavigationIntent(Intent intent) {

   if (null == intent)
      return false; 

   String scheme = intent.getScheme();

   if (null==scheme || (!scheme.equals("google.navigation") && !scheme.equals("geo")))
       return false; 

   String data; 

   if (null == (data = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()))
       return false; 

    // parse data to get longitude, latitude, and possible address dependent on callers
    // formatting

    return true; 

}
```

I activated navigation from google maps, and from robin, both produced a list with my app in it, and when selected it recognized the intent etc.

If you had previously checked the tick box for using google navigator (or any other program other than your ) as the default for Robin then you app will not start.

You would have to clear robin's data so it no longer had the default preference associated (kind of a nuclear option but it's the only way I found to un-associate this)

When I set it to use my app as default it always just started it and gave me the correct scheme and data package.

Screen Shots showing robin with list of apps that can start intent (mine is Navigation Test)

[image: Robin]

[image: My App Listed when navigation was pushed]

Comment: looks promising, trying out! tks a lot.

Comment: Hi Idistic, I tried it out, but seems my apps can't catch the navigation intent, what should I check?

Comment: @TungMaiLe what app is generating the intent and which app's are currently showing up in the list to handle it?

Comment: @TungMaiLe also I am assuming you are putting the intent in the same block as you main activity?  I don't think it checks permissions but you might try adding access coarse and fine, as well as internet in your manifest.  This works ok in and app I have when I ask for navigation from google maps ...

Comment: Oh I just checked again (by logging), the scheme that my application gets is null.
Yes I did put the intent in the same block as the main activity. All permissions you mentioned are included in the manifest.
I'm using Robin(a Siri-like apps for Anroid) to generate the intent.
Currently just the Google navigation apps showing in the list.

Comment: So it starts you app but there is no scheme in the intent? Huh. I will have to take a look at this, it's pretty late here so I will take a look tomorrow and see if I forgot something obvious.

Comment: Oh pls discard my previous comment about "the scheme that my application gets is null". It was on because I started the apps myself.

Comment: @TungMaiLe I wrote a very simple test app and updated the source above, no real changes, everything works see additional notes above and maybe try the simple app I posted above.

Comment: hmm, you mentioned something about "your device is rooted", yes, it is rooted. How's yours? 
(I'm testing the path 'clearing Robin' data).
Tks for your conscientious follow-up.

Comment: yes, it worked with the your sample code, did pop up in the apps list. Now I need to check my real apps again. Tks a lot. If only I could upvote twice on your answer!